# what does the empty regex match in ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

following a RoR security tutorial [(here)](http://oldwiki.rubyonrails.org/rails/pages/AuthenticationWithAbstractApplicationController), i wrote something along the lines of

```
@@private_re = //
def secure?
  action_name =~ @@private_re
end
```

the idea is that in the base case, this shouldn't match anything, and return `nil`. problem is that it doesn't. i've worked around for the time being by using a nonsensical string, but i'd like to know the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The empty regular expression successfully matches every string.

Examples of regular expressions that will always fail to match:

- `/(?=a)b/`
- `/\Zx\A/`
- `/[^\s\S]/`

Comment: /somethingthatwillnevermatch/ works the same and is a bit more readable :)

Comment: @kolosy ...it would match the text string `somethingthatwillnevermatch` :D - not that that is likely to be something you're testing... but its possible! :D

Answer (score 1):

It is meant to not change the behavior of the controller in any way, as `//` will match every string.

The idea is that `@@private` is meant to be set in the controller to match things you DO want to be private. Thus, that code is meant to do nothing, but when combined with 
`@@private = /.../` in the controller, gives you a nice privacy mechanism.

Comment: it may be meant to do nothing, but if used verbatim in the application controller, causes a redirect loop when there isn't a logged in user. the regex matches everything, kicks you to sign in, the regex matches everythign, kicks you to sign in, etc.